# Try Run readOGR from R on Java

Tags: java, r, gis, rjava, rgdal

I have Java properly running under JVM Oracle Version 7.x, on windows machine Seven. I can run Java calling R through eclipse or command line. But I'm stuck in a function related to GIS, named `readOGR`, who works well under R console but I can't figure out what's happened on Java environment. I'm looking for get the data content from the "Census2011_NUTS3_generalised20m" through `readOGR` function as mentioned before, but after a lot of research, I decided ask any help for community. Even other person could have similar issue.
I know that, probably I'm forgetting something, but all advices and ideas, even defferent by this approach are very welcome.
Below goes attached the code that shows what I expect (the top one, on R console), and in the bottom, the java code trying to do something similar.

The code below works well on R console:

```
install.packages('rgdal')
install.packages('ggplot2')
install.packages('util')

library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(utils)
irelandCensusFile_ <- readOGR("C:/Users/solver/Desktop/geographical_distribution/shinyWebApp/Census2011_NUTS3_generalised20m", layer = "Census2011_NUTS3_generalised20m")
View(irelandCensusFile_ )
```

The code below not works well on from JAVA:

```
Rengine re = new Rengine(null, false, null);
REXP x = null;

re.eval("install.packages('utils')");
re.eval("install.packages('rgdal')");
re.eval("install.packages('ggplot2')");
re.eval("library(rgdal)");
re.eval("library(ggplot2)");
re.eval("library(utils)");
re.eval("ogrDrivers()");
String path = "C:\\Users\\solver\\Desktop\\geographical_distribution\\shinyWebApp\\Census2011_NUTS3_generalised20m\\";
String name = "Census2011_NUTS3_generalised20m";
System.out.println(x);
//x=re.eval("readOGR(\""+path+"\", layer = \""+name+"\")");
re.assign("x"," a <- readOGR(\""+path+"\", layer = \""+name+"\")");
System.out.println(re.eval("x"));
```

PS.: I have no problem with `rJava` integration, just with this function.

Comment: There is no image attached.